# How to activate virtual environment while working on django project?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have been through numerous similar questions and I still don't understand how are we activating virtual environment for Django projects. Please mention explanation for how each command works and one more questions is that why do we not need to install python in Django's virtual environment, I am getting confused. Thank you in advance, please help this newbie.

Answer (score 2):

**Benefits**

- You can use any version of python you want for a specific environment
  without having to worry about collisions (shoutout to my python 2.7
  mac users!)
- You can organize your packages much better and know exactly the
  packages you need to run your code incase someone else needs to run
  it on their machine
- Your main python package directory does not get FLOODED with
  unnecessary python packages

**To create virtual environment**

*step 1 install environment package (virtualenv) using pip*

```
pip install virtualenv
```

*step 2* create virtualenv

```
virtualenv env_name #<- env_name is virtualenv name you can set any
```

*step 3 Activate Virtual env*

```
env_name\Scripts\activate #<- for window
```

*step 4 Install pakages you wan to install in virtual env*

```
cmd(env_name): pip install django
```

> Note that python is install in your virtual env automaticaty the
> version is same as in your local machine

Comment: Thanks, you made it easier for me.

Comment: Sorry I got one more question, is virtual environment need to be activated only while installing packages or it needs to be activated all the time when I am working on my project ( like while creating an app, making migrations etc )

Comment: In shourt yes! while working in project you must activate the virtualenv so your project can access  the pakages it required

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between activating virtual environment for Django or for other purposes. Django on it's own does not differ from any Python library out there.

Python virtual environment allows you to separate your system Python and it's libraries and create self-contained directory tree that contains a Python installation for a particular version of Python, plus a number of additional packages.

On Linux, assuming you already have Python 3 and pip3 installed:

```bash
# install virtualenv package (skip if you have it already)
pip3 install virtualenv
# create virtual environment in directory "tutorial-env" 
python3 -m venv tutorial-env
# activate virtual environment
source tutorial-env/bin/activate
```

Upon activation below command should give path to new Python binary:

```
which python3
```

Similarly with pip3

```
which pip3
```

As long as your environment is activate you can run `pip3 install $package_name` and it will install it inside virtual environment.

To deactivate your virtual environment:

```
deactivate
```

For more info and commands for Windows:
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html